# What algorithm is used in windows compression?

Tags: windows, compression

I looked into this link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it said that windows uses LZ algorithm. But which LZ does it use? I know there are many variants? Is it LZNT1? since it said it uses NTFS

Comment: Another 20 seconds of Googling would have revealed the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being impatient :)